# Selenium WebDriver и активный браузер

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Можно ли как-нибудь с помощью Selenium WebDriver узнать url активной вкладки? Браузер до запуска программы уже должен быть открыт, а не вызывать

```
ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
```

Вот код, который ищет активные вкладки без помощи Selenium WebDriver

```
        var roots = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"));
        foreach (AutomationElement root in roots)
        {
            var textP = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
            var vpi = textP.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
            Console.WriteLine(vpi);
        }
```

Но он сильно активно нагружает ЦП.
А с помощью Selenium WebDriver я так и не понял, как найти ссылку активной вкладки уже заранее запущенного браузера. И вообще можно это сделать с помощью Selenium WebDriver?

**UPD**

Ну или как-нибудь можно адаптировать метод с Autmation

Comment: Насколько мне лично известно, пока что вроде нет разработок в плане подключения к уже запущенному браузеру. Этот вопрос многим интересен.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium WebDriver работает только со своими процессами браузера, который запускает при инициализации `WebDriver`

Answer (score 0):

Если вывести в месседжбокс,то вот так:
    browser.SwitchTo().Window(browser.CurrentWindowHandle);

```
MessageBox.Show(browser.Url);
```

browser - это объект интерфейсного типа IWebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так :

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String url =  driver.Url
```